# Writing a generic 'fill' method

Tags: scala, collections, scala-collections

I am trying to write a generic `fill` method, and following is what I have come up with so far:

```
scala> import collection.generic.{GenericTraversableTemplate => GTT}
import collection.generic.{GenericTraversableTemplate=>GTT}

scala> import collection.generic.{TraversableFactory => TF}
import collection.generic.{TraversableFactory=>TF}

scala> def fill[A, CC[X] <: Traversable[X] with GTT[X, CC]]
     |   (n: Int)(elem: => A)(tf: TF[CC]) = tf.fill(n)(elem)
fill: [A, CC[X] <: Traversable[X] with scala.collection.generic.GenericTraversab
leTemplate[X,CC]](n: Int)(elem: => A)(tf: scala.collection.generic.TraversableFa
ctory[CC])CC[A]

scala> fill(3)('d')(List)
res42: List[Char] = List(d, d, d)
```

This works with all traversable collections except arrays. How do I make this code work with arrays?

Comment: I have also come up with [this](https://gist.github.com/1194858) alternative version which works with arrays, but I don't like it for two reasons: 1. It requires me to give more type annotations than I would like. 2. It makes me write the whole implementation myself instead of reusing existing methods in the collections.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you don't mind creating an extra object, there's

```
def fill[CC[_]](n: Int) = new {
  def apply[A](elem: => A)(implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, CC[A]]) = {
    val b = cbf()
    1 to n foreach { _ => b += elem }
    b.result
  }
}
```

It doesn't get around objection (2), but the usage is nice:

```
scala> fill[List](3)("wish")
res0: List[java.lang.String] = List(wish, wish, wish)

scala> fill[Array](3)("wish")
res1: Array[java.lang.String] = Array(wish, wish, wish)
```

Comment: I think I figured out how to get around objection (2). Check my answer below. (Although I feel there possibly is a better way.)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to change the syntax of Rex' solution a little bit:

```
class Filler(n: Int) {
  def timesOf[A](elem: => A) = new Builder[A](elem)

  class Builder[A](elem: => A) {
    import scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom
    def fillIn[CC[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, CC[A]]) = {
      val b = cbf()
      for (_ <- 1 to n) b += elem
      b.result
    }
  }
}
implicit def int2Filler(n: Int) = new Filler(n)

// use as
(3 timesOf true).fillIn[List]
```

Because operator notation is only allowed for parentheses, we can't omit the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I have bettered Rex's solution here by using `Builder`'s `++=` method. Use any collection, perform on it whatever operations you want to perform, and then finally add it to the builder object and then take its result.

```
scala> def fill[CC[_]](n: Int) = new {
     |   def apply[A](elem: => A)
     |               (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, CC[A]]) = {
     |     val b = cbf.apply
     |     b ++= Vector.fill(n)(elem)
     |     b.result
     |   }
     | }
fill: [CC[_]](n: Int)java.lang.Object{def apply[A](elem: => A)(implicit cbf: sca
la.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,A,CC[A]]): CC[A]}

scala> fill[List](3)("hullo")
res8: List[java.lang.String] = List(hullo, hullo, hullo)
```

Comment: I guess that's "better" if you don't mind it taking twice as long (because you build the same collection twice).

Comment: @Rex: How else can I reuse functions from stdlib instead of rolling out a builder-based imperative implementation?

Comment: Maybe you can't, but a lot of the helper functions are trivial to re-implement.